# python / os.listdir/ reading subfodlers

Tags: python, directory

Using python 3.5 on OSX
There are 5 subfolders in '/Users/abs/Desktop/data' and I am trying to look all the subfolders. But i got an error NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/abs/Desktop/data/.DS_Store'
How do I fix this problem

```
data_path = '/Users/abs/Desktop/data'
data_dir_list = os.listdir(data_path)

for dataset in data_dir_list:
    img_list=os.listdir(data_path+'/'+dataset)
    print ('Loaded the images of dataset-'+'{}\n'.format(dataset))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip the entries that raise the exception:

```
import os
data_path = '/Users/abs/Desktop/data'
data_dir_list = os.listdir(data_path)

for dataset in data_dir_list:
    try:
        img_list=os.listdir(data_path+'/'+dataset)
        print ('Loaded the images of dataset-'+'{}\n'.format(dataset))
    except NotADirectoryError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

If depth is fixed, `glob` is a good idea:

```
import glob,os.path
fd3 = glob.glob('/Users/abs/Desktop/data/*/*/*')
dd3 = filter(lambda f: os.path.isdir(f), fd3)
for f in dd3:
    print(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the dataset is a directory.

```
data_path = '/Users/abs/Desktop/data'
data_dir_list = os.listdir(data_path)

for dataset in data_dir_list:
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(data_path, dataset): # <-- if it is a directory
        img_list=os.listdir(data_path+'/'+dataset)
        print ('Loaded the images of dataset-'+'{}\n'.format(dataset))
```